# Azure AD B2C verification email customization

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

What steps are needed to customize the verification email sent by the Sign-up policy in Azure AD B2C?
 I have followed the [MSDN faq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs) and updated the Company branding with a banner image and a background color. 
However the email which is sent is still the default email and my edits of the branding are not applied.

EDIT:
According to this page it seems as the Azure AD B2C need to be upgraded in order to use the company branding:
[image] 
Is this correct? And if so, how can i upgrade the tier to premium? 
It seems odd since it was possible to edit the company branding without upgrading the tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now resolved.

This problem was caused by a bug in Azure.
After communication with the developer team they fixed it and the company branding started working.

To clarify: you don´t need to upgrade anything in order for company branding of the verification e-mail to work.

Comment: my customizations under Azure AD B2C >
Users and groups - Company branding >
Edit company branding are ignored. I modified the "Banner Logo", "Square logo image" and "Sign-in page background color" but the verification email looks the same. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @Helikaon I have read that updates can be delayed a while before appearing. But if it has been more than an hour I would recommend  creating a ticket in Azure and describe the problem. My problem was due to a bug in my B2C directory that needed to be fixed by the Azure B2C team.

Comment: you are right, it just took a while to take effect, thanks!